# Capturing ASP.NET MVC Errors and WebActivator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, webactivator

I want to know if it's possible to capture unhandled errors without modifying the web.config or global.asax files.

Ideally I would use the WebActivator package and have something like this:

```cs
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.Initialize), "Start")]

namespace MyProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    internal static Initialize
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
              // this doesn't work
              HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Error += ApplicationInstance_Error;
        }

        // this never fires
        static void ApplicationInstance_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question #1:**  Is it possible to capture unhandled errors without modifying the web.config or global.asax files?

**Question #2:**  How?

**Update:** I posted an answer below.  I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.  Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something working using this method:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyProject.Initialize), "Start")]

namespace MyProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    internal static Initialize
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new WatchExceptionAttribute());
        }
    }

    public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            // do your thing here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesnt solve errors 404 etc. Primary purpose of HandleErrorAttribute is handling internal unhandled exceptions.